# How to import a python script stored in another folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have a file named "**generate_tax_report.py**" which is stored at location "**C:\Users\rites\Desktop\crypto-tax-report\van\adam**".

[image]

Within file "**generate_tax_report.py**", I need to import a python script "fifo.py" which is stored at location "**C:\Users\rites\Desktop\crypto-tax-report\van\adam\inventory_methods** as seen in below image".

[image]

I have written:`from van.adam.inventory_methods import fifo`, but getting error as

`File "c:\Users\rites\Desktop\crypto-tax-report\van\adam\generate_tax_report.py", line` `13, in`  `<module>` `from van.adam import transactions as t ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'van.adam'; 'van' is not a package`

Edit: Added structure of van folder:
[image]

Comment: What does your `van` directory look like? It should have an `__init__.py` script. Also, how are you calling `generate_tax_report.py`? Are you running `python generate_tax_report.py`? If so, what is your working directory?

Comment: Hi @ogdenkev , I have edited the question with structure of van directory. I am running ```python generate_tex_report.py file```. My working directory is: **C:\Users\rites\Desktop\crypto-tax-report\van\adam"**

Comment: Have you installed van as a package?

Comment: @ogdenkev I am trying to import python scripts stored with vim\adam\ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have not installed `van` as a package, the problem is that when you run `python generate_tax_report.py` from `Desktop/crypto-tax-report/van/adam`, Python does not add `Desktop/crypto-tax-report` to the path, so `from van.adam.inventory_methods import fifo` fails because Python does not know about van.

If you moved `generate_tax_report.py` to `Desktop/crypto-tax-report` and then ran `python generate_tax_report.py` from `Desktop/crypto-tax-report`, it should work.

Alternatively, you could leave everything as you have it set up, but run `python -m van.adam.generate_tax_report` from `Desktop/crypto-tax-report`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try on this

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\rites\\Desktop\\crypto-tax-report\\van\\adam\\inventory_methods')

import fifo
```

worked on windows machine and print variable value in destination file

[this is an example of importing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EREI.png)

Comment: mo is the file you put his folder location in sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\path to file ')

Comment: I tried this, but this is also not working.

Comment: I edited the answer for your path could you try it